# Undefined keyword: connect to database & disconnect from database while doing database testing using robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, database, robotframework

Settings:

```
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     DatabaseLibrary


Suite Setup       Connect To DataBase       pymysql     ${DBName}    ${DBUser}    ${DBPass}    ${DBHost}    ${DBPort}
Suite Teardown    Disconnect From Database
```

Variables:

```
${DBHost}         127.0.0.1
${DBName}         mydb
${DBPass}         root
${DBPort}         3306
${DBUser}         root
```

Test cases:

```
Create person table
    [Tags]    db    smoke
    ${output} =    Execute SQL String    CREATE TABLE person (id integer unique,first_name varchar(20),last_name varchar(20));
    Log    ${output}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${output}    None
```

When I mouse hover on "Connect to database", I get an error:

> Undefined keyword: connect to database
> Create person table
> | FAIL |
> Parent suite setup failed:
> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)")

Comment: The error is quite expressive - on attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1, it failed as there was no service accepting connections on the host and port.

Comment: is the DB 'mydb' exists?

Comment: Yes, mydb is installed and it's also up.